# RobustScaler partial_fit() similar to MinMaxScaler or StandardScaler

Tags: scikit-learn

I have been using RobustScaler to scale data and recently we added additional data that is pushing the memory limits of fit_transform. I was hoping to do partial_fit in subset data but looks like RobustScaler does not provide that functionality. Most of the other scalers (MinMax, Standard, Abs) seem to have partial_fit.

Since I have outliers in the data, I need to use RobustScaler. I tried using MinMax and Standard scalers but outliers influence the data too much.

I was hoping to find an alternative to doing fit_transform for large dataset, similar to partial_fit in other scalers.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Due to the nature of RobustScalar, it is not possible to do partial_fit. So, we instead split our data vertically (by feature columns?) and use multiple RobustScalars to scale. We save which columns were scaled by which instance of RobustScalar and persist that information. It actually works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a hard requirement for you to use scikit-learn, you can perhaps check out another library for Biomolecular Dynamics called [msmbuilder](http://msmbuilder.org/3.7.0/index.html).

It claims to have RobustScaler similar to scikit-learn and with the option of using partial_fit, this is as per their documentation.

**Link:** http://msmbuilder.org/3.7.0/_preprocessing/msmbuilder.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html#msmbuilder.preprocessing.RobustScaler

---

***PS:*** I have not tested it.

Comment: Thank you. Code base already uses scikit-learn for other purposes so I wasn't exploring other libraries. I will check it out. Appreciate it!